# Angular js Summernote dropdown not closing when clicked outside editor

Tags: angularjs, summernote

I am using summernote with angularJS. The issue is when I open the dropdown within summernote editor and not select any options and click else where within the page I still see the dropdown. I wanted the dropdown to be hidden as soon as I click outside the editor. How do I achieve this?

My html code is.

`<summernote id="summernoteId" config="options" ng-model="x.responseTitle" placeholder="Enter title"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, Use directive to close Summernote dropdown.

```
angular.module('clickOutside', [])

.directive('clickOutside', [ '$parse', '$timeout', function($parse, $timeout) {
        return {
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            function handler(event) {
              if(!$(event.target).closest(element).length) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                  $parse(attrs.clickOutside)(scope);
                });
              }
            }

            $timeout(function () {
              // Timeout is to prevent the click handler from immediately
              // firing upon opening the Summernote.
              $(document).on("click", handler);
            });
            scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
              $(document).off("click", handler);
            });
          }
        }
    }]);
```

Include  `clickOutside` as directive  in DOM :

```
<summernote clickOutside id="summernoteId" config="options" ng-model="x.responseTitle" placeholder="Enter title"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Anil for the reply but somehow its not working. I did a really bad hack to hide like below. Any suggestions welcomed.

```
$scope.formClicked = function()
     {
        var list = document.getElementsByClassName("note-hint-item");
        if(list.length > 0){
          $(".note-hint-popover").attr("style", "display:none");
         }
     }
```